# Could not find table 'spree_pages'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am trying to get the [spree-static-content](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_static_content) up and running. I am currently using:

1. `gem 'rails', '4.2.3'`
2. `gem 'spree', '3.0.4'`
3. `gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'`
4. `gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'`
5. `gem 'spree_editor', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_editor', branch: '3-0-stable'`
6. `gem 'spree_static_content', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_static_content', branch: '3-0-stable'`

However, when I start running my rails server, 
I will receive the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Spree::StaticContentController#show
Could not find table 'spree_pages'
raise(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid, \
  "Could not find table '#{table_name}'") if structure.empty?
```

Answer (score 1):

Gem’s [README](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_static_content):

```
bundle exec rails g spree_static_content:install
```